Estimating errors on negative mass spec intensity measurements
I am writing mass spectrometry data reduction software, and have found myself in the awkward position of needing to estimate errors on negative intensity measurements.
While obviously the ideal approach involves configuring the mass spectrometer and software to never encounter negatives, I must estimate such errors regardless as users may, for example, use an overly aggressive baseline correction or feed the program a failed analysis in which the measurements are pure noise with no signal. I cannot simply say "Sorry, but you don't get errors on such measurements."
While we lack some knowledge to calculate the 'true' errors, we may estimate them from three sources:

Poisson statistics - The mass spectrometer's measurements effectively amount to ion counting.
Baseline/noise - Errors from the baseline correction.
Reproducibility - the system's ability to reproduce the same measurement. We estimate this as the percent standard deviation of the fitted peaks of seven subsequent gas standards, and apply this as a standard error. Because gas standards are very high intensity and high partial pressures, we assume that this fails to capture the above sources of error which dominate at low to moderate pressures and are therefore modeled independently.

It is #1 in particular that presents a problem with negative intensities. My proposed solution, based on modifications of a now-deleted answer from the Physics stackexchange on a similar question, is to use Bayesian statistics to estimate the "true" measured intensity.
$$
\newcommand{\ycount}{y_\text{count}}
\newcommand{\ystray}{y_\text{stray}}
\newcommand{\tdwell}{t_\text{dwell}}
\newcommand{\error}[1]{\varepsilon_{#1}}
$$
Let:

$y'$ be the measured intensity in amperes
$b$ be the baseline intensities with mean $\bar{b}$ and standard deviation $\sigma_b$, made at 5.5 amu where no gaseous species exist
$y$ be the baseline-corrected intensity, or $y = y' - \bar{b}$
$\tdwell$ be the dwell time over the given mass
$q$ be the charge of an electron
$\varepsilon$ indicates the error or variance on a measurement

Consider that each measurement $y'$ is a combination of the desired intensity of counted ions $\ycount$, the intensity of stray ions striking the detector $\ystray$, and instrumental noise $\epsilon$:
$$y' = \ycount + \ystray + \epsilon$$
Because we lack independent measurements of the noise and stray ions, we must estimate both from the baseline measurements $b$. We therefore approximate that:

$\ystray = \bar{b}$ with Poisson-distributed errors when $\bar{b} > 0$, otherwise $\ystray = 0$.
The noise $\epsilon$ is normally distributed around zero with variance $\sigma_b$, or:

$$\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_b)$$
As for the Poisson counting and errors, the number of ions $N_i$ associated with intensity $\ycount$ is:
$$N_i = \frac{\ycount\tdwell}{q\rho}$$
where $\rho$ is the ratio of counted ions to electrons from the Secondary Electron Multiplier (SEM), used to amplify signals. $\rho$ is measured by turning the SEM off, measuring seven gas standards, turning it back on, and measuring another seven standards: $\rho$ is the ratio of intensities with and without the SEM for each measured mass.
This makes the error in $\ycount$
$$\varepsilon_{\ycount} = \sqrt{\frac{q\ycount}{\rho\tdwell}}$$
When $y' \gg b$, we approximate $\ycount$ as the baseline-corrected intensity $y$. When $y' \lessapprox b$, we instead use a Bayesian approach to estimate $\ycount$ for the noisy measurement $y'$:
The probability of observing $\ycount$ is given by:
$$P(y') = \int_0^\infty P(y'|\ycount)P(\ycount)d\ycount$$
where:

$P(y'|\ycount)$ is the probability of observing $y'$ given $\ycount$:

$$P(y'|\ycount) = 
        \frac{
            1
            }{
                \sqrt{
                    2
                    \pi
                    \left(
                        \error{\ystray}^2
                        +
                        \sigma_b^2
                        +
                        {\left(
                            y'
                            \error{y'}
                        \right)}^2
                    \right)
                }
            } 
            \exp
            \left(
                -\frac{
                    {\left(
                        y' 
                        - 
                        \ycount
                        -
                        \ystray
                    \right)}^2
                }{
                    2
                    \left(
                        \error{\ystray}^2
                        +
                        \sigma_b^2
                        +
                        {\left(
                            y'
                            \error{y'}
                        \right)}^2
                    \right)
                }
            \right)
$$

$P(\ycount)$ is the prior probability of $\ycount$, a log-normal distribution that includes $0 \leq \ycount \leq 1\times10^{-9} A$ (note: typical baselines are around 1e-15 to 1e-13, however, for high total pressures, this may increase to 1e-12 to 1e-11):

$$        P(\ycount) = \frac{1}{\ycount \sigma_b \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left( -\frac{\left(\log(\ycount) - \log\left(\ystray\right)\right)^2}{2\sigma_b^2} \right)$$
The posterior probability of $\ycount$ given $y'$ is given by Bayes' theorem:
$$P(\ycount|y') = \frac{P(y'|\ycount)P(\ycount)}{P(y')}$$
The most probable value of $\ycount$ is then the mean of the posterior distribution:
$$\ycount = \int_0^\infty\ycount P(\ycount|y')d\ycount$$
This makes the total error on $y$:
$$\varepsilon_y = \sqrt{\sigma_b^2 + (y\varepsilon_{y'})^2 + \varepsilon^2_{\ycount} + \varepsilon^2_{\ystray}} = \sqrt{\frac{q(\ycount + \ystray)}{\rho\tdwell} + \sigma^2_b + (y\varepsilon_{y'})^2}$$
The threshold between these two regimes is defined by the relative variances between the Poisson and baseline errors:
$$\text{Var}(\ycount) = \frac{q\ycount}{\rho\tdwell}$$
$$\text{Var}(b) = \frac{q\ystray}{\rho\tdwell} + \sigma^2_b$$
The threshold between the regimes is:
$$1 = \frac{\text{Var}(\ycount)}{\text{Var}(b)}$$
Solving for $\ycount$ gives the threshold:
$$\ycount = \bar{b} + \sigma^2_b \frac{\rho\tdwell}{q}$$
Basically, I am looking for criticisms, suggestions for improvement, or whether I have done something stupid here as I am completely new to this Bayesian thing.

Is the amplifier offset fixed, or is it set based on some observable variables?  (In which case, which ones and how?)

It should be fixed, however, it can be dynamic. It is determined by:
"...send[ing] the MS to a particular mass (you specify) then it additionally shuts down the mass filter to allow nothing to the detector before measuring the offset in each range. The offset is then applied to the data before you see the result."
(quote from the mfct)

Basically it is a measure of how many stray ions are hitting the detector when the MS's mass filter is not throwing anything at it.

That is meaningless to 99% of people on this site.  You are going to have to translate your explanations to a form that can convey essential information to non-physicists.

A MS uses some means of ionizing gases and then uses a mass filter to determine which ionized masses are being detected. Let's say we want to measure helium-4 at 4 amu for 4 seconds: for four seconds, the mass filter is going to optimize its charge such that ionized particles with a mass of 4 amu are most likely to hit the detector. I phrase this as the mass filter "throwing" ions at the detector.
To measure the amplifier offset, the mass filter is turned off and nothing is "thrown" at the detector. We only measure the intensity of ions that happen to randomly bump into the detector.

I think you will have better luck on the Physics Stack.

Your actual measurement is of intensity and dwell time. You are inferring a count from that to get the Poisson count error, but it's clear that there is error beyond Poisson due to the characteristics of the measurement device. Restricting your error estimate to the Poisson error thus seems wrong. In general, it's best to work in the original measurement scale. This sounds like a situation that might be handled by a Bayesian model of the intensity itself that incorporates as a prior your understanding of the non-Poisson error process.

If I was able to model the error on the amplifier offset, I would, however, this is plain impossible. I do not know the amplifier offset for each system, nor what the error on such a measurement would be. I do measure and correct for the baseline, which is conceptually similar but physically distinct, and propagate errors on that, however, for the amp offset it's impossible. Therefore the Poisson distribution is as close as I'm likely to get for these data. Perhaps I am wrong, though! I would be interested in hearing more about a Bayesian approach.

@Ben the physical mode and it's statistical model is not too difficult. You observe a signal from excited electrons but there are two sources. One source is the actual signal of interest and occurs from ions (that you want to count) entering the amplifier and they excite electrons which you measure. Another source is thermal noise, electrons that randomly excite themselves spontaneously due to thermal variations Those electrons are counted as well but do not relate to the signal of interest....

...So the observation is Poisson distributed and we could say that without the signal the observed electron count value is distributed as $$X_0 \sim Poisson(\lambda_0)$$ and with the signal on the observed electron count value is distributed as $$X_{signal} \sim Poisson(\lambda_0+\lambda_{signal})$$ now, given obsevred $X_{signal}$ and $X_0$ we wish to infer $\lambda_{signal}$, what to do when $X_{signal}<X_0$? So it is not the raw data that is negative, but it is the difference $X_{signal}-X_0$ that is negative.

Your previous question was "Dealing with negative data in a Poisson distribution". Now it changed into  'I am mostly looking for any refinements to this approach which may better account for the errors in these measurements." .... If you already got answers to the old question, then for a complete change of the question you can better create a new question and leave this one as it was. This keeps the answers valid.

Your new question is not very clear and neither focussed. When you post your new question, then think about that. Not clear: Is your question about the error estimates for the points not falling within the range of a linear fit? Why should they? Explain more about that. not focussed: Is your question about the error bars being too small, or is your question about whether the Bayesian method for the estimation is correct?

"The standard error in $y'$, or the system's repeatability. This is measured as the percent standard deviation of the peak" Isn't this the overall error? Namely $y'$ is the signal, and measuring it's standard deviation experimentally adds up the errors from all the different sources. It includes the error due to Poisson randomness in the signal and the background.

Does your mass spectrometer have an electron multiplier which amplifies the current? You compute the number of electrons $n_e$, but that might be a multiple of the number of ions that hit the sensor. In that case, the Poisson standard deviation should be based on the number of ions, not on the number of electrons.

If the mass spectrometer is not filtering very well then this baseline measured at 5.5 amu might contain parts of nearby signals. It may not be the true noise. Also, if the spectrometer measures differently at different masses (e.g. use different bandwiths, voltages/amplification , etc.) then this can also influence the noise.

I apologize as it's sometimes unclear to me when a new question vs a revision to the old question is appropriate. Clearly, in this case, I made a mistake by revising the question. My question is primarily about the error bars being too small.

I do not believe the repeatability/standard error in $y'$ captures the Poisson counting errors or the baseline/noise errors, because the gas standards used to measure that repeatability are five to seven orders of magnitude above the baseline. Given the high intensity of the gas standards, I don't think this really captures the Poisson or baseline errors, which should be modeled separately. Unfortunately we don't have smaller gas standards to measure this over a range of values instead, which would be my preferred approach.

Yes, the mass spec uses an SEM which amplifies the signal and therefore estimating errors based on the number of electrons is an underestimate. I am working on an empirical solution to this that involves measuring gas standards both with and without the SEM, then comparing the ratio of the two average intensities for each mass.

"the gas standards used to measure that repeatability are five to seven orders of magnitude above the baseline." that was information that you left out. The errors related to small signal or small counts will indeed become negligible. Although you get a new error which is potential saturation of the system. Be aware that you might have new errors for large signals. For example the linearity of the SEM is less when it gets potentially oversaturated, and ....

... and that behaviour can change from experiment to experiment. For example, there might be voltage fluctuations after switching off and on the machine which influences the experiment in your non-linear range, but not in the linear range. Also dwell times might influence the oversaturation. The longer the measurement, the more it influences the non-linearity. So at higher signal strength you can experience variations in the multiplication by the SEM and your standards might show a variation that does not occur at lower concentrations). Maybe make a gas mixing system to test concentrations?

I suggest that you turn this question back into it's old form. This question about the size of the errors and how to estimate them is much more about experimental details which you can better ask on the chemistry site. If you do have some purely statistical question, then you can ask it here. But the answer is a bit trivial. If your theoretically computed errors are different from the variation that you observe, then something went wrong. Statistics can't help you much there.

I've converted the question back to its old form. Thanks for your patience.

I appreciate your insights on saturation, however, we don't really have an easy way to measure what that threshold is and how it affects measurements. Furthermore, the vast majority of our measurements are of very small volumes. Standards are well below saturation in the linear range, however, some sample gases (that aren't repeatable) may hit that range. It's very rare, though, and in such cases the impetus would be on the user to reduce their sample extraction time or laser power to reduce the total gas measured per analysis.

@ohshitgorillas There is a way to figure out the saturation. I remember optimizing a SEMs voltage by tracking the strongest signal that I could have as function of the voltage. As you increase the voltage the signal increases up to a certain point where it becomes saturated and it starts to plateau. You could do the same approach with your strongest signal.

NOTE THAT THIS ANSWER IS OUT OF DATE. IT ADDRESSES A PREVIOUS PROBLEM AND THE QUESTION ABOVE HAS BEEN SIGNIFICANTLY MODIFIED. I am leaving it here as whuber's comment below still contributes to the discussion.
THIS COMMENT has been further edited to include $y_\text{stray}$ to address concerns below.

A previous answer on a different stackexchange website (physics) nailed this problem, however, their answer seems to have been deleted. I will attempt to reproduce it here.
As comments have pointed out, negative intensities come from the fact that the error in the system is not only Poisson-based.
Consider that raw measurements $y'$ consist of the desired intensity of counted ions $y_\text{true}$, the undesired intensity of stray ions striking the detector $y_\text{stray}$, plus instrumental noise $\epsilon$:
$$y' = y_\text{true} + y_\text{stray} + \epsilon$$
While $y_\text{true}$ and $y_\text{stray}$ are Poisson distributed and thus $\geq0$, $\epsilon$ may cause small values of $y'$ to be negative.
Because we lack independent information on $y_\text{stray}$ and $\epsilon$, we estimate both from the baseline measurements ${b}$, measured at 5.5 amu where no gaseous species exist. We therefore approximate that:

Noise is normally distributed around zero with error $\sigma_b$:

$$\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_b)$$

$y_\text{stray}$ is the mean baseline intensity $\bar{b}$ with errors given by Poisson counting statistics.

When $y' \gg \epsilon$, we assume that $y_\text{true}$ is the baseline corrected value $y$, or
$$y = y' - \bar{b}$$
however, when $y' \approx \epsilon$ or $y' < 0$, we use a Bayesian approach to estimate $y_\text{true}$ given the prior knowledge that $y_\text{true} \geq 0$. The probability of observing $y_\text{true}$ given a noisy measurement $y'$ is given by:
$$P(y'|y_\text{true}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(\sigma_b^2 + y^2_\text{stray})}} \exp\left(-\frac{{(y' - y_\text{true} - \bar{b})}^2}{2(\sigma_b^2 + y^2_\text{stray})}\right)$$
The posterior probability of $y_\text{true}$ given $y'$ is:
\begin{equation}
P(y_\text{true}|y') = \frac{P(y'|y_\text{true})P(y_\text{true}}{P(y')}
\end{equation}
where the denominator, $P(y')$, is:
\begin{equation}
    P(y') = \int_0^\infty P(y'|y_\text{true})P(y_\text{true}) dy_\text{true}
\end{equation}
The error in $y_\text{true}$, denoted $\varepsilon_{y_\text{true}}$ is then the standard deviation of the posterior distribution, making the error in $y$:
$$\varepsilon_y = \sqrt{\varepsilon^2_{y_\text{true}} + \varepsilon^2_{y_\text{stray}} + \sigma^2_b}$$
IN ADDITION TO ADDRESS whuber'S COMMENT
With regards to the assertion that the baseline noise is not normally distributed, I present these concatenations of the baseline measurements for three systems. These each are composed of tens, if not hundreds, of thousands of measurements.




This answer fails at the point it assumes a Gaussian distribution of the errors: this is extremely unlikely because the Poisson distribution assumption tells us the observations are integral.  I think the basic problem is that the question and this answer don't adequately distinguish among parameters, counts, errors, and observations (measurements).

I will revise my question to be more generalized as well as to distinguish between parameters better.

@whuber I can't tell if your objection is with regards to the fact that I am assuming noise is Gaussian or whether it's with combining this Gaussian noise with the Poisson statistics into the same error term. Either way, I'm quite confused by your objection. Can you please elaborate?

Please see the addendum to my answer

I cannot determine what any of your new graphics mean, because they aren't adequately labeled; but all three depict strongly non-Normal distributions.

The plots depict histograms of tens of thousands of baseline measurements from three different systems.

I have edited this comment to separate the counted aspect of $b$ as $y_\text{stray}$ from the noise aspect $\epsilon$. I hope this is satisfactory.

Your histogram here shows signal currents up to the order of $10^{-13}$ which is similar to your signal at 4 amu. Is that supposed to be the case, that you have nearly zero signal at 4 amu? You could apply your Bayesian approximation technique to 'solve' it, but it is a flimsy method. What you would want instead is a system that doesn't need such tricks and that has a better signal to noise ratio that is much above unity. (longer dwell times can solve this for example, but that might not be practical for you).

Yes, it's common when measuring blanks that we don't see much 4 amu, it's typically near or just above the baseline, however, it's also the case that those higher baseline measurements tend to accompany rather high total pressures, whereas it's lower when we are measuring basically no helium-4.

And yes, obviously, we wish to avoid negative intensities as much as possible, however, the point is that my program is going to have to deal with them regardless, whether it's by the user selecting the wrong baseline correction technique or giving the program an analysis in which the ion source failed and the measurements are all noise/nonsense. I therefore need SOME way to address those measurements, flimsy though they and their resulting "correction" may be.

This relates to several other questions

How best to estimate regression parameters subject to constraints?
According to your model, negative values of the parameter are not possible. However, your measurements can be negative.
(you say that you are dealing with Poisson distributed data, but actually you have a difference and negative observations can occur)
How to deal with the constraint depends on what you want to do with it. What is the problem when you estimate a negative value? Is it just that it doesn't feel right theoretically? If you apply some cost function for your predictions, then this problem should disappear like snow in the sun.

When is it ok to remove the intercept in a linear regression model?
In my answer to the above question, I mentioned that it can be reasonable to exclude the baseline/intercept from a model.
The final decisive argument whether or not to include a baseline/intercept should not be whether it makes theoretically sense, but instead whether or not it makes your estimates better.
You experience negative values, how are they problematic for you? Approach them pragmatically. They might be theoretically unsound. But just because of that, they aren't already directly a problem.
Again, the matter should be ultimately decided by a cost function. How do you quantify negative errors? If you wish to penalize them with infinity cost, why?

Not exactly related but analogous is If $X$ is normally distributed, can $\log(X)$ also be normally distributed?
One might answer with a 'no' to such question by noting that the Gaussian distribution has negative values and one can not take the logarithm of a negative value.
However, this ignores that the practical application might be different from the exact theoretical description/model.
The same is true for your example. Your model assumes that negative observations/statistics are not possible, but that's an ideal situation. Since you are subtracting two values, you can get negative values. The model is not perfect.
Also related is Regression model with (almost) non-negative residuals where a person assumed that some value could not be negative, but due to computing a difference between two non-negative values, they might obtain a negative value.


